# How to return the area of the rectangle by using length and width Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
function getRectangleArea(length, width) {
 //return the area of the rectangle by using length and width
 // code here
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.mathsisfun.com/area.html . If you have a specific question wrt how to implement this in JavaScript please ask it. But you have to at least try *something*, not just ask others to implement it for you.

Comment: Are there any ideas?

Comment: return length*width

Answer (score 1):

Area of rectangle is equal to `length*breadth`. We simply pass two arguments and return their multiplication :)

Try this:

```
function getRectangleArea(length, width) {
  return length*width;
}

let area = getRectangleArea(4,5);

console.log(area);
```

Comment: but as per the instruction console.log will not work?

Comment: I didn't got it :) Are you looking for something else :) If you run above code, you wil get the results you want. Only that you have to pass two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, adding a little control on length and width it's not a bad idea

```
function isNumber(value){
  if (typeof value === 'number') return true;
  else return false;  
} 

function getRectangleArea(length, width) {
    if(isNumber(length) && isNumber(width)) {
        return length*width;
    }
 }

let area = getRectangleArea(14.6,5.1);

console.log(area);
```

@NoobProgrammer you can also *try something* in your own playground https://jsfiddle.net/francesco77/4pu1m6vb/3/